# error con JQuery en Mozilla Firefox

Tags: php, jquery

Como dice el titulo, no puedo ejecutar un JS dentro de Mozilla (en chrome funciona correctamente), pero en este ultimo no.

Mi codigo:

Boton Agregar Carrito

```
<input type="submit" class="btn-tarificar" name="tarificar" value="Tarificar" />
```

JQuery

```
    jQuery("input[name='agregarcarrito']").on('click', function(e) {
        if (!jQuery(".condiciones").is(":checked")) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('Debe aceptar las condiciones del envío.');
        } else {
<?php if($num>4) { ?>
            alert('Máximo 5 items en el carrito.');
<?php  } else { ?>
            $('.form-envio').attr('action', "carrito.php").submit();
<?php } ?>
        }
    });
```

Les dejo el carrito.php que es donde se pasan las variables

```
<?php
/* Carga de cabecera y menu */
include_once('inc/header.php');
include_once('inc/sidebar.php');
//include_once('encabezado.php');
session_start("2");
if($_GET['indice']=="" && $_POST['txtpaisDestino'] !="") {
    foreach($_POST as $nombre_campo => $valor) { 
        if($nombre_campo!='mt')
            $_SESSION[$nombre_campo][]=$valor;
        else
            $_SESSION['mostrartransferencia']=$valor;
    }
}
?>

    <script language="javascript">
        function iratransferencia() {
            var person = confirm("Esta seguro de hacer la transferencia con los datos del carrito?");
            if (person == true) {
                window.location = "inc/transferencia_carrito.php";
            }
        }

        function iraformulario() {
            window.location = "formulario.php";
        }

        function vaciarcarrito() {
            window.location = "carrito.php?vaciar=0";
        }
    </script>

    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <form class="form-tarjeta" action="" method="post" target="">
        <input type='hidden' name='Ds_SignatureVersion' value=''>
        <input type='hidden' name='Ds_MerchantParameters' value=''>
        <input type='hidden' name='Ds_Signature' value=''>
    </form>
    <form class="form-envio" action="ejecutarenviosgrabar_paypal_carrito.php" method="POST" name="form1">
        <fieldset>
            <table border="1" cellpadding="15">
                <tr>
                <td>Origen</td><td>Destino</td><td>Fecha del Envio</td><td>Contenido del Envio</td><td>A Pagar</td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
                </tr>
....
```

Si necesitan algun codigo mas, me avisan, aunque creo que esta todo para que lo vean.

El codigo no es que no funcione, simplemente no funciona en Mozilla, en Chrome funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Donde esta la libreria `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js`?

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con que no funciona? ¿Qué es exactamente lo que pasa en Firefox, aparece algún error en la consola? Por cierto, no es buena idea combinar Javascript y PHP, de alguna forma deberías tener en Javascript el contador de productos para evitar esa mezcla que podría fallar si hay cambios en el DOM.

Comment: muestra el error que te está dando en específico, pueden ser muchas cosas